# Moving wordpress from /dir to main folder

Tags: directory

I have a simple question.

I want to move my wordpress installation from [www.xclo.co.uk/dir](http://www.xclo.co.uk/dir) to [www.xclo.co.uk](http://www.xclo.co.uk)

Please can someone tell me how to do this.

Comment: Have you read the Codex article: [Moving WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)?

Comment: Yes but I do not understand. How do I do it?

Comment: You do not understand any of it? Or you do not understand part of it? If so, which part do you not understand?

Comment: I'm taking it that I need to read this bit "When Your Domain Name or URLs Change". But there is no wp-posts in my directory

Comment: You misread that option. It is for searching a database table named wp_posts. It is not a directory. If you are unfamiliar with querying a database, use option 2. I think there is a plugin to do search and replace, but you need to know Perl regular expressions to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you backup everything then:

- Move the content of `/dir` one level up, make sure you move hidden files as well (I care about the `.htaccess` file and maybe a `.git` folder)
- Download [Search & Replace for WordPress](http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/), upload it to your server
- Access it with the url: http://www.xclo.co.uk/searchreplacedb2.php
- Follow the instructions, in brief, the script will read the database details from your wp-config.php and allow you to specify the change that you want to be made in the database, in your case you want all occurencies of `www.xclo.co.uk/dir` to be replaced by `www.xclo.co.uk`.

**Tip**: since you mentionned you URL publically, I suggest you rename the script before you upload it, otherwise your database connection details will be exposed.